# How to have curl or httpie access subdomains locally with Rails 5

Tags: curl, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, httpie

I'm building an API with Rails 5 and trying to test post requests locally on the command line with either curl or [httpie](https://httpie.org/).

However, I'm using `constraints subdomain: 'api'` in my routes and both curl and httpie don't like that. If I open Chrome and go to `http://api.localhost:3000/v1/users`, I receive a valid response. However, with httpie I get this error:

```
    http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.localhost', port=3000): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/users (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x105732550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] 
nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)) while doing GET request to 
URL: http://api.localhost:3000/v1/users
```

I'm almost certin this is due to the subdomain but I can't find any documentation anywhere that refers to using subdomains with curl or httpie. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's what I did:

Since I'm using a linux environment, I went to /etc/hosts and added a custom local host name called `api.stevenlocal.com`.

In my Rails app in `environments/development.rb` I made sure the following line was set to `1`:

```
 # Allow constraint subdomain for routes
  config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 1
```

Setting it 1 tells rails that the top-level domain is going to be after one period (in this case, stevenlocal is the top-level domain and it is after .com). This is important because then Rails knows to look for my subdomain essentially after two periods (`subdomain(first-period)top-level-domain(second-period)com`). *Rails by default has this line set to 1 but I had previously changed it.*

Now on the command line, when I try `http api.stevenlocal.com:3000/v1/users`, it works as expected. *Note that http is a curl like command used with the [httpie](https://httpie.org/) command line tool*